# How to abstract common function out from the test file in Cypress

Tags: javascript, async-await, e2e-testing, cypress, testcafe

I just moved from **TestCafe** to **Cypress** and couldn't find a solution to abstract a common frequently used method. In this example below `cy.document().then(doc)..` is used twice, however I believe that these types of function must be abstracted to reusable function.

```
it('Test the input text field and submit button list the basket items', () => {
const allNameBeforeInput = []
const allNameAfterInput = []
cy.document().then((doc) => {
    const elements = doc.querySelector('#items').querySelectorAll('.row-style > :nth-child(1)')
    for (let i = 0; i <= elements.length - 1; i++) {
        const basketName = elements[i].textContent
        if (basketName && basketName !== '') {
            allNameBeforeInput.push(`${basketName}`)
        }
        console.log(allNameBeforeInput.length) //this gives 0
    }
})
cy.get(basket.itemInputField)
    .type('Suraj')
cy.get(basket.submitInputButtonField)
    .click()
cy.get(basket.itemInputField)
    .type('Suraj')
cy.get(basket.submitInputButtonField)
    .click()
cy.get(basket.itemInputField)
    .type('Suraj')
cy.get(basket.submitInputButtonField)
    .click()
cy.get('#items').children('.row-style').children('.list-item')
    .contains('Suraj')
cy.document().then((doc) => {
    const elements = doc.querySelector('#items').querySelectorAll('.row-style > :nth-child(1)')
    for (let i = 0; i <= elements.length - 1; i++) {
        const basketName = elements[i].textContent
        if (basketName && basketName !== '') {
            allNameAfterInput.push(`${basketName}`)
        }
    }
    console.log(allNameAfterInput.length) //this gives 3 
    expect(allNameBeforeInput.length).equal(0)
    expect(allNameAfterInput.length).equal(3)
    expect(allNameBeforeInput.length).is.lt(allNameAfterInput.length)
})
```

})

This is what I want to accomplished with class Basket:

```
getAllBasketName() {
    cy.document().then((doc) => {
        const allName = []
        const elements = doc.querySelector('#items').querySelectorAll('.row-style > :nth-child(1)')
        for (let i = 0; i <= elements.length - 1; i++) {
            const basketName = elements[i].textContent
            if (basketName && basketName !== '') {
                allName.push(`${basketName}`)
            }
        }
        return allName
    })
}
```

Now I should be able to use

```
    const getAllBasketNamesBefore = basket.getAllBasketName()
cy.get(basket.itemInputField)
        .type('Suraj')
    cy.get(basket.submitInputButtonField)
        .click()
    cy.get(basket.itemInputField)
        .type('Suraj')
    cy.get(basket.submitInputButtonField)
        .click()
    cy.get(basket.itemInputField)
        .type('Suraj')
    cy.get(basket.submitInputButtonField)
        .click()
    const getAllBasketNamesAfter = basket.getAllBasketName()
{Assertion goes here}
```

This is not working because of async/await is not handled so the value of before and after are alway 0. Any clue or help will be appreciated.

Comment: I will take a look, but I am wondering if there is a better way to test this. you can add a function in command.js or you could just add a function in your js code and call it, but I assume you know that and you are asking something else and I don't understand that you are trying to accomplish. Let me look at your code harder.

Comment: @Maccurt I am trying to do the add function in js code and call it, but couldn't accomplish it. Can you show one example with it.

Comment: I realise this isn't related to your question but I am really curious. What was the decision to move from something that supports many browsers to something that just supports Chrome and what's so much better about Cypress? I've been working on the Open-source project Courgette https://github.com/canvaspixels/courgette and was wondering what features are drawing everybody to Cypress

Comment: When you first look Cypress it looks like from the other planet, for example: the cy command are async function but they are not pure async. They are spiced with retry-and-time out. The basic of cypress is it puts you in such a position where avoid writing flaky test becomes the norms. Your concern about multiple browser support is under way and in my case chrome is more than enough. I have done couple of project in TestCafe which support all the browser but my experience was not as smooth as Cypress. At the moment I think there is no better tools than Cypress for JS testing at the moment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method you are using is not recommended by cypress and is considered an anti-pattern.  https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/best-practices.html#Assigning-Return-Values

Cypress recommends that you add custom commands.  https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/custom-commands.html#Syntax

In the initially created folder structure, the commands.js file can be found under the support folder.  Here you are able to create a command that wraps up the logic you wish to reuse.  Based on the console.log portion of your code I assume this is run on the command line.  There are custom commands for the console as well as for use in the UI.

for that portion you may have to add this custom command

```
// not a super useful custom command
// but demonstrates how subject is passed
// and how the arguments are shifted
Cypress.Commands.add('console', {
  prevSubject: true
}, (subject, method) => {
  // the previous subject is automatically received
  // and the commands arguments are shifted

  // allow us to change the console method used
  method = method || 'log'

  // log the subject to the console
  console[method]('The subject is', subject)

  // whatever we return becomes the new subject
  //
  // we don't want to change the subject so
  // we return whatever was passed in
  return subject
})
```

For the other functionality creating commands is pretty simple, the basic pattern is:

`Cypress.Commands.add(name, callbackFn)`

so you can potentially create something like

```
Cypress.Commands.add(allNameBeforeInput, (options, options) => {
 //custom logic goes here

})
```

Then you can use it by calling cy.allNameBeforeInput(options, options).

For instance, I was struggling with login and all my tests had login functions to log in through the UI but I wanted to start my tests on the correct page instead of the the log in page.  I added this to the command.js file in the support folder:

```
Cypress.Commands.add('login',(username="notsharingmyusernam@stackexchange.com", 
password="somesecurepasswordshhh") => {
 cy.request({
   method: "POST",
   url: "/api/public/login",
   body: `{:person/email "${username}", :person/password "${password}"}`,
   headers: {
     "Accept": "application/edn",
     "Content-Type": "application/edn"
   }
 })
})
```

And now I can add the cy.login and a beforeEach function at the beginning of my tests.  The before each to make the request to the server and wait for the request for login and the cy.login custom command to ensure that I can use that bundled up logic with just one cy command.

```
describe('Test suite for page traverse', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        cy.server()
        cy.route("POST","/api/graphql").as("graphql")
        Cypress.Cookies.preserveOnce("company_jwt_qa") 
    })

     it('traverses all subnav items', () => {
        cy.login()
            cy.visit('/index.html')
            cy.wait("@graphql")
        cy.get('[data-tag-component="subnav-group"]')
            cy.get('[data-tag-component="subnav-title"]').eq(1).click()


    })
 })
```